# What does the browsers target in babel-preset-env do exactly?

Tags: babeljs

The [docs for `babel-preset-env`](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env) state, that it allows specifying target browsers for transpilation with a browserslist query. The example given is a query of ">0.25%, not dead" to ignore "browsers without security updates like IE 10 and BlackBerry".

But setting `debug: true` to show what targets are being used by babel, it seems as if only a fixed subset of the browserlist query is actually taken into account ("android, chrome, edge, firefox, ie, ios, safari").

```
$ cat .babelrc
{
  "presets": [["@babel/env", { "modules": false, "debug": true }]]
}

$ cat .browserslistrc
last 1 version
not dead

$ echo "const fn = (...args) => args;" | npx babel -f test
...
Using targets:
{
  "android": "67",
  "chrome": "67",
  "edge": "17",
  "firefox": "61",
  "ie": "11",
  "ios": "11.3",
  "safari": "11.1"
}
...

$ npx browserslist
and_chr 67
and_ff 60
and_qq 1.2
and_uc 11.8
android 67
baidu 7.12
chrome 67
edge 17
firefox 61
ie 11
ie_mob 11
ios_saf 11.3-11.4
op_mini all
op_mob 46
opera 53
safari 11.1
samsung 7.2
```

So should it be possible to e.g. target Opera Mini? Or is the documentation misleading?

E.g. "last 1 version, not dead, not ie 11, not android 67" will *not* transpile arrow functions - even though they are not supported by some targeted browsers according to [caniuse](https://github.com/Nyalab/caniuse-api) ("and_qq 1.2", "ie_mob 11", "op_mini all")

---

EDIT:
I think this has to do with `babel-preset-env` getting the browser support data from [`compat-table`](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table) (and not [`caniuse`](https://github.com/Nyalab/caniuse-api) or [`browser-compat-data`](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data))?

Comment: Wondering this myself... and_uc for example is huge and I know for a fact it has a far smaller subset of implemented features... does the data maybe just not exist for these browsers so they're being excluded?

Comment: It seems [caniuse](https://github.com/Nyalab/caniuse-api#api) does have data for these browsers.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe and_uc effectively is covered by targeting a min version of chrome and/or android, therefore it is omitted? If not it seemed like a bug.